# NPM not installed with the latest Node version

Tags: node.js, npm

I have the latest Node version and according to https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm NPM comes with the latest version

```
$ - node -v
v0.12.0
```

I try to see what version of NPM is installed

```
$ - npm -v
-bash: /usr/local/bin/npm: No such file or directory
```

When installing NPM via Terminal as the link above suggests I get the following error

```
$ - curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   193  100   193    0     0    172      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--   172
100  6239  100  6239    0     0   2797      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--  7636
tar=/usr/bin/tar
version:
bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
install npm@latest
fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.7.0.tgz
unbuild npm@2.5.1
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/4b/qrlv75j55nxd4_k63vv964n40000gn/T/npm.3664/package/cli.js" "rm" "npm" "-gf"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/4b/qrlv75j55nxd4_k63vv964n40000gn/T/npm.3664/package/npm-debug.log

> npm@2.7.0 prepublish /private/var/folders/4b/qrlv75j55nxd4_k63vv964n40000gn/T/npm.3664/package
> node bin/npm-cli.js prune --prefix=. --no-global && rm -rf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j8 doc

make: Nothing to be done for `doc'.
npm ERR! Darwin 13.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/private/var/folders/4b/qrlv75j55nxd4_k63vv964n40000gn/T/npm.3664/package/cli.js" "install" "-gf"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.7.0
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm'
npm ERR! error rolling back     at Error (native)
npm ERR! error rolling back  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: -13,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' }

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /private/var/folders/4b/qrlv75j55nxd4_k63vv964n40000gn/T/npm.3664/package/npm-debug.log
It failed
```

I get the same error when running `sudo curl -L https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh`

Comment: How did you install node? You should not need to execute `install.sh` to get npm anymore...

Comment: @mscdex through nodejs.org and clicking install

Comment: I don't understand why my question was downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it. On my root directory `cd ~` I entered `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local` and then ran the curl command again with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your error looks like it's due to an access thing (if you read the error), so check permissions on the file path listed.

Your first problem might be similar; I'd try and locate the npm executable and see what permissions are there even before trying to install it again.

Comment: Would you mind giving me more precise steps to do so?

Comment: Looks like you fixed it.  Basically, use ls -la to see what permissions the folder in question have, then either chown or chmod to change them to what's needed (usually r-x for the current user or the owner, depending on what you're trying to support).

Answer (score 0):

There's an excellent video on NPM's website that gives you a few options on how to fix this depending on your needs. Worked for me.

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions